# Create fake data to use as tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create fake usage of my app, as a tutorial.

In order to do so, I need to create fake data (with the same structure and association in real data) to send to my templates, so it renders the same view when my users will have when using the app.

But unfortunately, I didn't find an easy way to do that, except hard coding the examples (fake usage) as a separate view, that looks like the generated view with true data. But this is not useful when you have to change the template, one day or another.

And, mixing true data with fake ones in the database (and then retrieving only fake data when needed) doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Do you have an idea or a gem to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

One option to consider is to use a factory gem (such as [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)) or similar (I personally like [machinist](https://github.com/notahat/machinist)) and then create some form of script that initializes objects in the test environment.

This may not be the intended or ideal use for a test environment, but you'd be able to utilize your app in a non-production environment with fake data, and allows you to keep data separate from real and/or development data.

The only "gotcha" I can think of is that you'll want to ensure that any automatic testing gem (such as rspec) drops the test database before your tests run.  If you don't, you could see errors in your tests due to data already existing in the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CDub. So, if I understand well, I can use factory_girl or machinist to generate fake data to display. Is this possible to do in production mode? Because the fake data should be visible to real users in the tutorial.

Comment: Sure, you could use either of those to generate data in production.  With factory_girl, you'd make sure the gem was available in the production group in your Gemfile, and for machinist, you can load the blueprints in the rails production console and add data that way.

Comment: And you may want to consider using the faker https://github.com/stympy/faker or forgery gem https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery/tree/master in conjuction